# How to retrieve the checked boxes value?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list containg checkbox in each row. I have to retrieve value of only checked boxes so that on button click those selected cases are closed. I am not able to retrieve the value. Below is my code

Visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="cases" extensions="CloseController" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll(cb,cbid)
    {
        var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                    
        for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
        {            
             if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf(cbid)!=-1){                                       
                inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Case List">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="ct" id="Selected_PBS">
       <apex:column title="Select">
         <apex:facet name="header">
           <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="checkAll(this,'checkedone')"/>
         </apex:facet>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ct.Select__c}" id="checkedone" />
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!ct.CaseNumber}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="Close Case" action="{!CloseCase}"/>
  <apex:outputField value="{!Case.Status}" rendered="false" />
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class CloseController {
  public Case cas;
  public CloseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {
    this.cas = (Case)stdController.getRecord();
  }

  public void CloseCase(){
    List<Case> csa = [Select Id, Status from Case];
    for(Case ccas:csa){
      ccas.status = 'Closed';
          update csa;
    }

  }
}
```

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

In your for look check whether the field is true (means checked) and update the status to closed only for those cases.

```
List<Case> lstCaseClose = new List<Case>();
for(Case ccas:csa){
    if(ccas.Select__c){
        ccas.status = 'Closed';
        lstCaseClose.add(ccas);
    }    
}
update lstCaseClose;
```

I have used a list to hold the cases to be closed and update it outside of the for loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: also you need to loop throught cases list , not csa list